# Proof of property of Markov chain

Tags: markov-chains

Given markov chain $X$, how to prove following property by markov property:
$$P(X_{n+1} = s | X_{n_1} = x_{n_1}, X_{n_2} = x_{n_2}, ...,X_{n_k} = x_{n_k} ) = P(X_{n+1} = s | X_{n_k} = x_{n_k}) ， \quad \forall 0 \le n_1 < n_2 < ...<n_k \le n$$
I can't figure out how to prove it?
Any hint?

Comment: It looks to me you are trying to prove the definition of a markov chain.  What am I missing?

Comment: @herbsteinberg Usually a (1-order) discrete Markov chain is defined by $P[X_{n + 1} = s | X_n = x_n , X_{n - 1} = x_{n - 1}, \ldots, X_0 = x_0] = P[X_{n + 1}  = s | X_n = x_n]$, i.e., in a contiguous manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pad the gap between $X_{n_j}$ and $X_{n_{j + 1}}$, $j = 0, \ldots, k$. Formally, this means we introduce the omitting random vectors $(X_{n_j + 1}, \ldots, X_{n_{j + 1} - 1})$ by $Y_{n_j}, j = 0, \ldots, k$ (fix $n_0 = 0, n_{k + 1} = n$).

By law of total probability and the Markov property:
\begin{align}
& P[X_{n + 1} = s | X_{n_k} = x_{n_k}, \ldots, X_{n_1} = x_{n_1}] \\
= & \frac{P[X_{n + 1} = s, X_{n_k} = x_{n_k}, \ldots, X_{n_1} = x_{n_1}]}{P[X_{n_k} = x_{n_k}, \ldots, X_{n_1} = x_{n_1}]} \\
= & \frac{\sum_{y_{n_0}, \ldots, y_{n_k}}P[X_{n + 1} = s, Y_{n_k} = y_{n_k}, X_{n_k} = x_{n_k}, \ldots, Y_{n_1} = y_{n_1}, X_{n_1} = x_{n_1}, Y_{n_0} = y_{n_0}]}{\sum_{y_{n_0}, \ldots, y_{n_k}}P[Y_{n_k} = y_{n_k}, X_{n_k} = x_{n_k}, \ldots, Y_{n_1} = y_{n_1}, X_{n_1} = x_{n_1}, Y_{n_0} = y_{n_0}]} \\
= & \frac{\sum_{y_{n_0}, \ldots, y_{n_k}}P[X_{n + 1} = s, Y_{n_k} = y_{n_k}| X_{n_k} = x_{n_k}, \ldots, Y_{n_1} = y_{n_1}, X_{n_1} = x_{n_1}, Y_{n_0} = y_{n_0}]P[X_{n_k} = x_{n_k}, \ldots, Y_{n_1} = y_{n_1}, X_{n_1} = x_{n_1}, Y_{n_0} = y_{n_0}]}{\sum_{y_{n_0}, \ldots, y_{n_k}}P[Y_{n_k} = y_{n_k} | X_{n_k} = x_{n_k}, \ldots, Y_{n_1} = y_{n_1}, X_{n_1} = x_{n_1}, Y_{n_0} = y_{n_0}]P[X_{n_k} = x_{n_k}, \ldots, Y_{n_1} = y_{n_1}, X_{n_1} = x_{n_1}, Y_{n_0} = y_{n_0}]} \\
= & \frac{\sum_{y_{n_0}, \ldots, y_{n_k}}P[X_{n + 1} = s, Y_{n_k} = y_{n_k}| X_{n_k} = x_{n_k}]P[X_{n_k} = x_{n_k}, \ldots, Y_{n_1} = y_{n_1}, X_{n_1} = x_{n_1}, Y_{n_0} = y_{n_0}]}{\sum_{y_{n_0}, \ldots, y_{n_k}}P[Y_{n_k} = y_{n_k} | X_{n_k} = x_{n_k}]P[X_{n_k} = x_{n_k}, \ldots, Y_{n_1} = y_{n_1}, X_{n_1} = x_{n_1}, Y_{n_0} = y_{n_0}]} \quad \text{(Markov Property)} \\
= & \frac{\sum_{y_{n_0}, \ldots, y_{n_{k - 1}}}P[X_{n + 1} = s| X_{n_k} = x_{n_k}]P[X_{n_k} = x_{n_k}, \ldots, Y_{n_1} = y_{n_1}, X_{n_1} = x_{n_1}, Y_{n_0} = y_{n_0}]}{\sum_{y_{n_0}, \ldots, y_{n_{k - 1}}}P[X_{n_k} = x_{n_k}, \ldots, Y_{n_1} = y_{n_1}, X_{n_1} = x_{n_1}, Y_{n_0} = y_{n_0}]} \quad \text{(Do the sum with respect to $y_{n_k}$ first)} \\
= & P[X_{n + 1} = s | X_{n_k} = x_{n_k}].
\end{align}

---

To answer your concern, we can prove in a more general sense, i.e., for any positive integers $m, k$, it follows that 
$$P[X_{m + k} = x_{m + k}, \ldots, X_{m + 1} = x_{m + 1} | X_m = x_m, \ldots, X_0 = x_0] = P[X_{m + k} = x_{m + k}, \ldots, X_{m + 1} = x_{m + 1} | X_m = x_m]. \tag{1}$$

By multiplicative rule and Markov property, the left hand side of $(1)$ equals to 
$$P[X_{m + k} = x_{m + k} | X_{m + k - 1} = x_{m + k - 1}] \cdots P[X_{m + 1} = x_{m + 1} | X_m = x_m],$$
whence to prove $(1)$, it suffices to prove 
$$ P[X_{m + j} = x_{m + j} | X_{m + j - 1} = x_{m + j - 1}] = 
P[X_{m + j} = x_{m + j} | X_{m + j - 1} = x_{m + j - 1}, \ldots, X_m = x_m].
\tag{2}$$
for $j = 1, \ldots, k$.

To prove $(2)$, let $Z$ denote the vector $(X_0, X_1, \ldots, X_{m - 1})$, again by law of total probability, the right hand side of $(2)$ equals to:
\begin{align}
& P[X_{m + j} = x_{m + j} | X_{m + j - 1} = x_{m + j - 1}, \ldots, X_m = x_m] \\
= & \sum_{z} P[X_{m + j} = x_{m + j}, Z = z | X_{m + j - 1} = x_{m + j - 1}, \ldots, X_m = x_m] \\
= & \sum_{z} P[Z = z | X_{m + j - 1} = x_{m + j - 1}, \ldots, X_m = x_m]P[X_{m + j} = x_{m + j} | X_{m + j - 1} = x_{m + j - 1}, \ldots, Z = z] \\
= & \sum_{z} P[Z = z | X_{m + j - 1} = x_{m + j - 1}, \ldots, X_m = x_m]P[X_{m + j} = x_{m + j} | X_{m + j - 1} = x_{m + j - 1}] \\
= & P[X_{m + j} = x_{m + j} | X_{m + j - 1} = x_{m + j - 1}]
\sum_z P[Z = z | X_{m + j - 1} = x_{m + j - 1}, \ldots, X_m = x_m] \\
= & P[X_{m + j} = x_{m + j} | X_{m + j - 1} = x_{m + j - 1}].
\end{align}

This completes the proof.

Comment: Why markov property implies $P[X_{n + 1} = s, Y_{n_k} = y_{n_k}| X_{n_k} = x_{n_k}]$

Comment: @Spaceship222 Good question, I edited my answer and added more details.